# Hibernate, Persistence and @OneToMany and @ManyToOne annotations problems

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, persistence, one-to-many

I have some problem with @OneToMany and @ManyToOne annotations.

I have two class Suite and SuiteVersion. A SuiteVersion is dependent of a suite. So i have implemented this in my code:

Class Suite :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "suite")
@Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
private List<SuiteVersion> listSuiteVersion = new ArrayList<SuiteVersion>();
```

Class SuiteVersion :

```
@ManyToOne()
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
private Suite suite;
```

But i have some problem when i delete a Suite whose have SuiteVersion associated.
Hibernate don't delete SuiteVersion before Suite.I don't know why because i have mentioned this in my code :

```
@Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
```

This the log i obtained when i delete suite :

> Hibernate: delete from SUITE where ID_SUITE=?
>   13 août 2010 09:40:50 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
>   ATTENTION: SQL Error: -8, SQLState: 23504
>   13 août 2010 09:40:50 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
>   GRAVE: integrity constraint violation: foreign key no action; FK42895651EA304E6 table: SUITE_VERSION

Thank you in advance for your help.

Best Regards,

Florent,

P.S : Sorry for my english i'm french.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But i have some problem when i delete a Suite whose have SuiteVersion associated. Hibernate don't delete `SuiteVersion` before `Suite`.

That's because you're **NOT** cascading the `REMOVE` operation from `Suite` to `SuiteVersion`. To obtain the desired result, you need something like this (assuming you're using JPA 1.0):

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "suite", cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.REMOVE)
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
private List<SuiteVersion> listSuiteVersion = new ArrayList<SuiteVersion>();
```

I used fully qualified names to clearly show the Hibernate specific and the standard JPA annotations here.

The Hibernate specific `CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN` is something else, it is used to tell Hibernate **to delete a specific `SuiteVersion` if you remove it from the collection** (without it, the `SuiteVersion` record would be updated to remove the link to the parent `Suite` but would remain in the table, being thus an "orphan").

Note that if you are using JPA 2.0 (i.e. Hibernate 3.5+), there is now a standard way to deal with orphan records i.e. without using the Hibernate specific annotation. You can specify an `orphanRemoval` option in your `OneToMany` (and `OneToOne`) association. Like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "suite", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<SuiteVersion> listSuiteVersion = new ArrayList<SuiteVersion>();
```

But this goes beyond this question as this is actually not what you're looking for.

Comment: You are right. DELETE_ORPHAN just works when you remove The associated Entity from The collection. (+1)

Comment: Thank you, this help me a lot. But i have juste move to jpa 2.0 before i learn your post. At the end of your post you speak about a new standard way to deal with orphan. Can you explain me this new way to deal this orphan ?

Comment: @Delildor: You're welcome. Regarding orphans with JPA 2.0, see my update.