# Deleting in a one to many unidirectional hibernate mapping

Tags: hibernate, jpa

what is the best practice of deleting a parent in a unidirectional hibernate mapping ? (I am using JPA)

```
Parent: 
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Child> children= new ArrayList<Child>();

Child:
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_parent")
private Parent parent;
```

Child is the owner of the relationship here, and I want to delete a parent which has children associated. How do I achieve it ? Should I go on and iterate children from parent one by one and delete them or there exists some other way. Unfortunately, did not find anything about deleting in hibernate docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in fact, your association is bidirectional, and not unidirectional...

If your goal is to delete the children when the parent is deleted, then all you need is

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private List<Child> children= new ArrayList<Child>();
```

and

```
em.remove(parent);
```

Comment: What if I have another Parent now, Parent1 with same relationship with Child (as Parent has). Can I delete parent without worrying about relationship between child-parent1 ?

Comment: em.remove(parent) did not work after adding Cascade, throws 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails ...'

Comment: I am getting this error "foreign key constraint fails ..." consistently with the one-to-many bidirectional and not able to get past it...  I have provided all CascadeTypes with no avail.

Comment: which foreign keyconstraint is failing? Are you sure you don't have any row with a foreign key to the parent? What are the SQL queries executed by Hibernate?

Comment: yes, I do have a row with fk to the parent. I assume cascade (cascade = CascadeType.ALL or REMOVE) will remove all children when I do em.remove(parent) . Looked at SQL queries executed by hibernate, and there is no delete issued for child rows !! Surprisingly, I do see delete statements being issued for other types of children (with same one-to-many relationship with parent) ! Why could this be ? I dont see any difference in the way I have mapped other child classes.

Comment: I meant rows with a foreign key to the parent, and which are not children of the parent. Try to test with a simple case, where the parent only has one kind of child, and where nothing else refers to the parent. And edit your post to show which SQL queries are executed.

Comment: Tried a simple case (which is/was working before adding this new child). Parent class Proj with one-to-many relationship with Doc. (with cascade settings CascadeType.ALL). Here are the hibernate statements: `Hibernate:
    delete
    from
        doc
    where
        id_=?
Hibernate:
    delete
    from
        proj
    where
        id_=?
Hibernate:
    delete
    from
        budget
    where
        id_=?
Hibernate:
    delete
    from
        proj_metadata
    where
        id_=?`  [here budget and proj_metadata have one-to-one relationship with proj].

Comment: So, everything works fine with the one-to-many: the child (doc) is deleted before the parent (proj). The problem is with your one-to-one associations.

Comment: what problem could that be ? budget and proj_metadata are getting deleted cleanly when I delete proj, no problems ever. Also found bizarre that em.remove(parent) does call delete of child, but only sometimes, and can not reproduce when. I can see the delete of child missing in hibernate sql logs in some cases...

Comment: Also as per [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474918/hibernate-persistence-and-onetomany-and-manytoone-annotations-problems) added orphanRemoval = true, still no avail. I think its something to do with cascade remove which is behaving intermittent. Cant figure why.

Answer (score 0):

Gosh ! Found the problem. It was nothing to do with cascade, well cascade was needed though. The problem was with the way I was adding the child to parent, and deleting them. So to sum up:

If I perform save on parent to create association :

```
parent.addChild(child)  
em.save(parent)
```

then I must operate from parent while deleting. Alternatively, if I add child as

```
child.setParent(parent)
em.save(child)
```

then I must operate on child to delete it etc..

Comment: There is no save() method in EntityManager. And the way an entity has been saved (potentially years ago, and potentially using something other than Hibernate), doesn't have any impoact on how you must delete it.

Comment: Yes, I know. its weird, atleast in my env. However, things start working when I redeploy, I guess then all associations are synched properly. [Will replace save with persist]